# I can't run the emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, terminal-emulator

I can't run the emulator, I don't understand I new created emulator and visual studio code because i got errors like this and i couldn't do it so i deleted it and reinstalled it. I added "android.overridePathCehck=true" because it was saying that I should add this into gradle.properties
I have Pixel 5 API 28 And start Pixel 6 Pro API 33

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The area where I saved the project contained characters other than English characters, so it was giving an error. I determined their location as a file containing only English characters and the error was resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).